# Temporary deny use of windows share

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, shared-folders

I would like to know if it is possible to temporary deny access to windows share folders for a specific user at a specific time range?

Example:
Deny access to user User1 for folder WolfyShare from 23:00 to 12:00
or 
Allow access to user User1 for folder WolfyShare from 12:00 to 23:00

If it is possible, can you tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in utility to do this, but you could accomplish it with a scheduled revoke of the user's permissions and then a scheduled change to put the permissions back.

In **Task Scheduler**, you would create a basic task of `cacls filename /r WolfyShare` at 23:00. This revokes all access permissions of the user.

Then to restore access, you would reverse the change with `cacls filename /g WolfyShare:f` at 12:00.

You would create similar tasks for the other user at the corresponding times.

To disconnet a user's session, you could use `net session \\computername /delete`, however this method would require the user always be using the same PC.

Read about cacls.exe on [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490872.aspx).
Read about how to disconnect a user using [`net session`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725598.aspx#BKMK_cp).

Comment: Thanks for this! I did it as you tell me (with Icacls), but in case that this user is already using a file (like video clip,...) this will not stop the use of this file... any ideas why? I also disabled cache (/cache:none)

Comment: I updated my answer